# Viewing the actual User ID in Google Analytics when using the User ID tracking feature

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I believe that I have correctly followed all the steps required to implement Google Analytics User ID tracking on my website. While I can see things like the User-ID coverage report, I can't actually see the User IDs themselves. For example, I'd like to see all the pages that user ID 17 visited yesterday, but I don't see any way to get that information. How can I find data for a specific user ID?

Answer (score 6):

### Updated Answer

Since you are wanting to actually report on the User ID you will need to set up a Custom Dimension to store it. After looking at [About User Data](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6066725?hl=en) and [Tutorial: How to send user IDs to Google Analytics](https://davidsimpson.me/2014/04/20/tutorial-send-user-ids-google-analytics/) I believe that will be the best solution.

In essence the same User ID that you are storing in the User ID field will also need to go to the Custom Dimension, or possibly just to the Custom Dimension.

### Original Answer

According to [Benefits of using the User ID feature](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123663): "When you set up the User ID, you can access *User ID reporting views* and the *Cross Device reports*.".

More information about the *User ID reporting views* can be found here, [About User ID views](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123669?hl=en).

If all else fails, and you want to pull out the raw data you can take a look at the [Google Analytics Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/).

Comment: I have read all those documents and none provide the answer I'm looking for. Do you see the answer in any of them?

Answer (score 3):

> [User ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id) enables the analysis of groups of sessions, across devices,
>   using a unique, persistent, and non-personally identifiable ID string
>   representing a user.

That being said when you add

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': 'USER_ID' });
```

to your tracking code Google Analytics uses the information in the background to help aggregate the data. Its used mostly to help iditntify uesrs across devices.

**Example:**

If I log in to your website that's one session, if I log into your mobile app that's a different session.  So Google Analytics would see it as two separate sessions.

If you send user id along with both calls Google Analytics knows this is me on both instances and I will be the same session and the same data when everything is calculated / processed in the background.

**Seeing the info:**

That being said User id is an internal value only, is not a value that you can see in the Google Analytics website you also can't see it via the API. User Id is only used in the background by Google Analytics.    If it is something that you want to see then you should be creating a custom dimension and storing it in there. as Adam Huffman suggested.

IF you do go the route of Custom dimension remember this must be a non-personal identifiable info. You cant send someone's email address for example.